# Teen TV show about a group of middle/high school friends who have adventures with dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, tv, dinosaurs

I remember watching this in 2007 in France, but as it was an American/English/Australian(?) show, I assume that it was released in 2005 or maybe 2006.

There were a group of friends in middle/high(?) school and they used to have many adventures which involved dinosaurs or prehistoric animals in general. I don't remember much more. I remember that at the end of the opening, there was a dinosaur egg hatching.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, was this **live-action or animation**? What were the teen's names? Can you remember any of the specific characters? Did they time-travel or were the dinosaurs around in modern times? How did they get there? What adventures did they have? Did the dinosaurs speak? Did they have any enemies/villains? Did they have any modes of transport? Did they have parents that appeared in the show? Where did they go to school?

Comment: Dino Squad? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oae-YzR7JFU

Comment: Sounds like [DragonTales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Tales) except with elementary school kids.